# Plot line from pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the dataframe below in pandas currently

```
|  x  | ID   | Num
|-----|------|-----
|  1  | 100  | 35
|  2  | 100  | 50
|  3  | 150  | 34
|  4  | 150  | 25
|  5  | 150  | 46
|  6  | 200  | 13
|  7  | 200  | 75
|  8  | 100  | 37
|  9  | 150  | 61
```

I'm trying to create a multi-line graph where the 'x' column is the index and on the x-axis, while the ID and Num columns form the lines.

I tried to do a single line version with just x and ID with the following code, but it returns nothing, and I'm not sure how to upgrade to a two line graph.

```
s1 = df_iter.resample('LowestAcceptedValue')
s2 = df_iter.resample('SwapsValue')
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
df.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` to put `x` as the data frame index, then plot the rest:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('x').plot()

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Generates this message: "<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x24a95b00>". Not an error, but that's the only output I receive

Comment: @Leggerless you need `plt.show()` to show the plot, first import plt as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed you had a plotting environment set up.  Dark is right - I'll update now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'ID': [100, 100,150], 'Num': [35,50,34]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

df.plot()
plt.xticks(df.index.values )
plt.show()
```